# Save excel formula in python, not able to update them when opening- Bloomberg

Tags: python, excel, bloomberg

I tried tot save formula inside an excel workbook; Bloomberg formula. It seems to work but When I open the workbook with python, I sometimes don't have my Bloomberg add-in in the excel instance or the formula don't update. 
When I do have the Bloomberg add-in, and try to refresh the Bloomberg I got a pop-up saying that the excel cannot connect to this add-in.

When I used another excel instance, my add-in is working and the same bloomberg formula written by hand works.

Here the code from python.

```
import pandas as pd
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application') 
File_location="K:/...'

EQU_list= pd.DataFrame(columns ['SECURITY','PRICE(LOCAL)','DVD_EX_DT','BDVD_NEXT_EST_EX_DT'])

EQU_list['PRICE(LOCAL)']=pd.DataFrame(['=BDP(A'+str(i+2) +' & " Equity","PX_LAST")' for i in range(len(EQU_list)+1)])
EQU_list['DVD_EX_DT']=pd.DataFrame(['=BDP(A'+str(i+2) +' & " Equity","DVD_EX_DT")' for i in range(len(EQU_list)+1)])
EQU_list['BDVD_NEXT_EST_EX_DT']=pd.DataFrame(['=BDP(A'+str(i+2) +' & " Equity","BDVD_NEXT_EST_EX_DT")' for i in range(len(EQU_list)+1)])

filename=File_location+'TSX60price2_'+dformat+'.xlsx'
EQU_list.to_excel(filename,sheet_name='Price',index=False,engine='xlsxwriter')

xl.visible=1
wb=xl.Workbooks.open(filename)
wb.RefreshAll()
import time 
# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(10)   
price=pd.read_excel(filename)
```

I also tried :

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook(Filename)
```

and :

```
import os
os.startfile(filename)
```

Without any success

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try the formula debugging steps recommended in the XlsxWriter [Dealing with formula errors](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-formula-errors) docs. In particular the formula that Excel stores and uses may not be the one it displays.

Comment: Any update on this. Did you get it working?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already looked at it before. My formula is right and the problem is the Bloomberg add-in that is not in the excel instance that python is supposed to  open,(the instance is on my normal excel instance).

Comment: Ok. I can't help you with that but I would like to find out, from an XlsxWriter point of view, if the Bloomberg formula works if the add-in available, since this is something of a FAQ. Maybe you can let me know, even if it doesn't relate to your problem.

Comment: Will let you know, but Im trying to explore other way to do it without excel since excel-python with bloomberg add-in don't seems to work.